# How to open a url in a new window in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on `button1` it should open the URL in Internet Explorer in a new window.

Comment: I'd like to suggest not doing so :) I dislike when web sites think they know how to manage my windows better than I do.

Comment: dnt worry i would be providing 2 links , 1 to open in the same window and new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="Button" value="Click me!" onclick='window.open("mypage.html", "refname", "resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");' />
```

Comment: thanx frnd (i forgot to say thanx , srry)

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="my_uri" target="_blank">
```

Although this does not guarantee a new window, some browsers prefer to open it in a new tab instead.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open